# Associar commit ao Issues do Bitbucket

Tags: git, commit, versionamento, bitbucket, controle-de-fluxo

Com o Bitbucket é possível trabalhar com "Issues", onde no caso poderia ser utilizado como "tarefas/bugs/etc...". A minha dúvida seria se é possível associar um ou mais commits a determinado "Issues".

Caso não seja possível, existe alguma ferramenta que possibilite trabalhar desta forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, podes usar `#<issue-number>` na mensagem do commit, tal como no GitHubt.

Exemplo retirado da documentação:

> fixes #6, resolve ticket #5 and see ticket #9 and ticket #5 in the tracker

Documentação: [Resolve issues automatically when users push code](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Resolve+issues+automatically+when+users+push+code)

Ceritifica-te que em Settings > Hooks aparece um hook chamado `Issues`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]